# Trying to Return top K Students

Tags: c, arrays, structure

```
struct student ** topKStudents(struct student *students, int len, int K) {

    student* top_students = (struct student *)(malloc(K * sizeof(struct student)));
    struct student temp;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < len - 1; j++)
        if (students[j + 1].score>students[j].score){
            temp = students[j];
            students[j] = students[j + 1];
            students[j + 1] = temp;

        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < K; i++){
            top_students[i] = students[i];
    }
    return &top_students;
}
```

There are no build errors in the code but i am getting addresses instead of values

Comment: Well for one thing, you're returning the address of a local variable.  That address is invalid as soon as the call returns, so it can never be correctly used.  Understand that the variable `top_students` is gone when the function returns.  I suggest returning its value rather than its address.

Comment: You could have avoided a lot of work by starting with something simpler: a function that returns the first two students.

Answer (score 1):

By making your function return a pointer to a pointer, you get one too many level of indirection: You return the address of a local pointer, but the pointer goes out of scope after returning, making that address invalid.

The solution here is to return the handle directly:

```
struct student *topKStudents(struct student *students, int len, int K)
{
    student* top_students = malloc(K * sizeof(*top_students));

    // fill array

    return top_students;
}
```

This design means that the calling code has to `free` the returned pointer later. Another possible design is to pass in an array and let the calling code take care of allocation:

```
int topKStudents(struct student *res, int K,
    const struct student *students, int len)
{
    // fill res

    return 0;
}
```

The return value can be a success value, e.g. 0 for success and −1 for failure, or it can return the size of the filles result array, which, depending on your function, may be less than `K`.

This design lets you allocate the result array on the stack, which is a good choice if `K` is small.

(This answer really deals with the problem of how arrays can be returned from functions. It does not deal with the problem at hand. Your code for returning the top students just sorts the original array, which means that you don't really have to return an array: After you have modified your array the top students are in the `K` first positions.)